# How to set the default route to the Help page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am working with a WebAPI 2 project and would like the default route to be the Help page. The help page works when I call it from the URL, but when I tried to set up a default route like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

);

I get an error message about a missing View:

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations

How can I set Help to work as the default?

Comment: Make sure you've "Index.cshtml" in "Views/Help" folder

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is because the Razor view is missing.

Look inside the following directory

```
Views > Help > Index.cshtml
```

Does that file exist in the directory? If not create it, and that should solve your issue.

If it does already exist, can you post your `Help` Controller and your `Index` Action

Comment: It's there. It is part of the package that gets installed. The Area registration bit was missing for Application_Start.

Answer (score 0):

The HelpPage system is installed into a HelpPage Area.

Areas need to be registered by placing the following call into the Application_Start of Global.aspx:

```
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```